# WEKA SMO vs. LIBSVM

Tags: weka, libsvm

Is WEKA's SMO different from LIBSVM?

I'm asking because it says on LIBSVM's [site](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) that:
`it implements an SMO-type algorithm proposed in this paper [...]`

Is there a difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

By the above statement the site meant that they use SMO in solving the quadratic programming (QP) problem that arises during the training of support vector machines, as previously available methods for SVM training were much more complex and required expensive third-party QP solvers.

You can get a more descriptive understanding of SMO [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization)

Answer (score 0):

LibSVM has more features that can be customized.

Here is a comparison table from this document
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2tuXEy73YswVFdPUTIwSHRPckU/view

from the ["Advanced Data Mining with Weka"](https://weka.waikato.ac.nz/advanceddataminingwithweka/) course, lecture 3

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Comparative study of he following two papers will make you understand the differences:
http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69644/tr-98-14.pdf
[http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf)